# Did J.K. Rowling ever explain how Harry Potter could see Orion during the O.W.L. Examination?

Tags: harry-potter, astronomy

How was Harry able to see the constellation, Orion, in the middle of summer in the far northern hemisphere? Did they use magic?

Comment: "As Harry completed the constellation Orion on his chart..." page 31 of chapter 31.

Comment: It's a practical exam, they're writing what they observed

Comment: I'm guessing Rowling is no better with astronomy than she is with math...

Comment: In a lifetime movie she's is portrayed as getting top marks on all subjects, including being a math wiz. I don't know how accurate it is though. Supposedly the school she came from wasn't a top one, else she would have gotten into oxford,  according to the movie.

Comment: Even nerds don't always check for accuracy. It's a fantasy book, not sci fi, like conservation of momentum and brooms is ignored.

Comment: Orion is indeed hidden by the Sun at Summer Solstice in the UK: [Chart](https://in-the-sky.org/skymap2.php?no_cookie=1&latitude=51.51&longitude=-0.13&timezone=1.00&year=2021&month=6&day=21&hour=12&min=0&PLlimitmag=0&zoom=160&ra=5.00423&dec=51.50853)

Comment: I can't say I know star charts well, just from experience,  like I know it ain't there cuz I never seen it during that time. Maybe some are more centaurish than others though.

Comment: Well I know what G.R.R. Martin would say to this question-- "put down your ruler and just enjoy the story."

Comment: Dissecting stories can be enjoyable also.

Comment: If this hasn't been brought up numerous times before, there may be no reason to think she's necessarily bad at astronomy, at least compared to most. She may have never taken the subject. But one doesn't need astronomy to see what they see at night.

Comment: I looked online more, the issue has been brought up in comments before.

Comment: Sort of beside the point, but you might like to use [Stellarium](https://stellarium.org/) to see what the sky would have actually looked like at the time Harry would have been making his observations.

Comment: Maybe Harry just sucks at Astronomy?

Comment: Muggles!  Try *Philips Sunlight Filter* this coming Summer! You'll be amazed! Once you've tried this bit of apparatus, you'll never go back to star watching on chilly nights ever again!

Comment: It could be what we muggles call a "trick question". The correct answer to the exam question may have been "Orion is not visible because <reasons>". Harry just got the question wrong. :P

Comment: Hogwarts is magic. Who's to say that, to prevent cheating (or to avoid potential interference from weather), the teachers didn't place a spell over the Astronomy tower to make it show different constellations during the O.W.L.s than are actually in the sky?

Answer (score 56):

**I believe this is a mistake by Rowling**

The O.W.L. exams are taken in June:

> ...June had arrived, but to the fifth years this meant only one thing: Their
> O.W.L.s were upon them at last.
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - Chapter 31: O.W.L.s</sub>

When Harry goes to take his Astronomy exam, it is 11pm:

> When they reached the top of the Astronomy Tower at eleven
> o’clock they found a perfect night for stargazing
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - Chapter 31: O.W.L.s</sub>

The entries they make on their charts are implied to be what they are currently observing:

> Professors Marchbanks and Tofty strolled among them, watching
> as they entered the precise positions of the stars and planets they were
> observing.
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - Chapter 31: O.W.L.s</sub>

I believe this quote suggests Harry was previously looking at Orion, before making an adjustment to look at Venus:

> As Harry completed the constellation Orion on his chart, however, the front doors of the castle opened directly below the parapet where he was standing, so that light spilled down the stone steps a little way across the lawn. Harry glanced down as he made a slight adjustment to the position of his telescope and saw five or six elongated shadows moving over the brightly lit grass before the doors swung shut and the lawn became a sea of darkness once more.
> Harry put his eye back to his telescope and refocused it, now examining Venus.
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - Chapter 31: O.W.L.s</sub>

He 'completed the constellation Orion on his chart', makes 'a slight adjustment to the position of his telescope' before 'now examining Venus'. I think this string of events heavily implies he was actually looking at Orion.

Using a [planisphere](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planisphere), I can confirm that the constellation Orion is not visible in the June sky in the Northern Hemisphere at 11pm. In fact, it doesn't appear in the sky *at all* in the hours that it would be dark in Scotland in June, from around 10pm to 5am. From quotes, his exam seems to take around 2 hours, but this is beside the point - his exam could have lasted the entire night and he still wouldn't have been able to see it. There are no quotes saying magic is used for observations during the exam, so I think it's safe to rule that out. It is simply a mistake on the author's part.

I can't say this with 100% confidence, but I've a suspicion that he couldn't see Venus then either given he's observing it after 11pm, and a June 1996 astronomy almanac makes no mention of it.

Comment: " I think this string of events heavily implies he was actually looking at Orion." Thanks for the quotes. I agree, that's a solid implication.

Comment: @Jonita Thanks for the comment, it was a fair point you made and I was glad to take it on board.

Comment: This is kinda reiterating my question, I was wondering if maybe a superfan were aware if she had given an explanation for this at some point, as I've heard she's done with other aspects from the stories. Certainly many people who read this must have gawked at the idea of seeing Orion at night in the summer in Scotland and some probably have brought it up to her, or maybe not.

Comment: It's impossible to prove a negative, so we can't say for certain that she hasn't said anything, but I think it's highly unlikely.

Comment: @user14094230 Unfortunately, I couldn't find any comment from Rowling regarding this particular issue. With the lack of any comment from her, and no quotes from the book explaining why Orion is visible, I can only surmise this is an error on the author's part, which I have then provided quotes and evidence for to substantiate it as a mistake. Sometimes the answers on Sci-Fi SE are just 'we don't know' or 'it's a mistake', sorry I couldn't help you any further. You never know, another user might come across something more useful, but I am doubtful.

Comment: Yes, if others more in the know about JK than me (which isn't much besides HP books and all the JK movies, though that last movie I had a hard time paying attention to the whole way through) haven't heard this issue addressed, then I would agree, it probably hasn't been addressed

Comment: @user14094230 I admit, my own HP knowledge is tiny compared to some people on this site, so there is a chance someone else will answer your question with something from Rowling. I think Demosthenes' answer is a good take, probably the best (annoyed I didn't think of it tbh), for an in-universe answer as to why Harry thinks Orion is 'visible' in June - Astronomy *isn't* exactly his strong suit as evidenced by his grade. Otherwise, if you read the text as he definitely did see Orion, we just have to chalk it up to a blunder by JK.

Comment: Isn't it impossible to see Venus at 11 pm from the UK?  It'd have to be summer at a very North location, with the sun up or just near the horizon all day, for Venus to be above the horizon so close to midnight.

Comment: @Ross Out of pure interest I actually looked a fair bit into this, and it is *possible* to see Venus around 00:00 in Scotland but in quite specific circumstances, and certainly not in June 1996, but I don't want to commit to it 100% as explaining it is probably an answer/question for somewhere more like Astronomy SE. But you are correct, it is essentially impossible anywhere in the UK.

Comment: Honestly, June is the worst possible time to do any kind of stargazing in northern Europe anyway. I'm not sure how well the latitude of Hogwarts has been specified, but even at the [southernmost point of Scotland](https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/@2648914) there's no true night at all, and even [astronomical twilight](https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/astronomical-twilight.html) won't start until well after 11 pm. And [it gets worse](https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/@9782404) the further north you go.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: I love the summer months for sidewalk astronomy. I can ask passers-by if they'd like to see the the double cluster, the double double, the Andromeda galaxy, or, when visible, the Moon, Saturn or Jupiter. They typically don't know what on Earth I'm talking about, and only want to eat their ice cream alone. 30s later, they're screaming like little children because they see Saturn rings for the first time.

Comment: @EricDuminil I distinctly remember how I screamed when I saw Saturn's rings for the first time! :)

Answer (score 30):

As @user14094230 already added in his comment, the exact quote from the book is:

> As Harry completed the constellation Orion on his chart, (...)

The most probable reason for that passage is that JKR sucks at astronomy.

But trying to find an in-universe answer, I would say that Harry simply made an error on his star chart. He was just a student taking an exam, from which he received "A" note (the lowest of pass grades). Astronomy has never been of Harry's high interest. It's likely he confused some other constellation with Orion, but most of his star chart was correct.

Comment: To be fair, completing a constellation on your chart does not require it to be in front of you. It could be part of the test to complete the constellations that are not visible based on the ones you can see. But that's reaching a bit.

Comment: Unlikely that he mistook it. Orion is one of the brightest and most easily recognized constellations.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron - Hence his shitty mark in the exam, surely?

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron Harry once wrote in an essay that Europa is covered with mice, do you remember? That makes confusing Orion a minor mistake...

Comment: Good points, maybe he screwed up, but with Orion it seems unlikely, but he didn't do well on the test, though they were distracted by the attack on Hagrid, and he wasn't the worst student. Maybe JK has yet to address this issue.

Comment: @user14094230 - "Address the issue"? Are you trying to get JK into **more** trouble? Just what she needs, NdeGT busting her chops.

Comment: Or alternatively, rather than "JKR sucks at astronomy", maybe ... "JKR recognises that the astronometrical accuracy of that passage is *utterly irrelevant* and has no significance whatsoever".

Comment: Unlike Tolkien, who ensured that the phase of the moon was consistent and correct throughout *The Lord of the Rings*, @Brondahl?

Comment: @TRiG, I've no idea whether Tolkien recognised that that stuff was irrelevant to the reader. Nothing in his world-building was done for the reader - he made all that stuff because he was an Uber-nerd who did that shit for fun :D (Reference: THoME, none of which was ever intended to be published - it was just his reference, for kicks.)

Comment: It's entirely possible that he didn't recognise that it was irrelevant. And it's entirely possible that he *did* receognise that it was irrelevant ... and decided to do it anyway.

Comment: Watch one of the interviews where astrophysicist Neil DeGrasse Tyson talks about his argument with director James Cameron over getting the stars wrong in *Titanic*.  (He brings it up somewhat frequently.)  Cameron's reaction is still priceless, something to the effect of: "*Titanic* was the highest grossing movie of all time when it came out - imagine how much more money it would've made if the stars were accurate?"

Answer (score 2):

I mean, JKR also doesn't understand that after the spring equinox, the days are longer the further North you are. In Deathly Hallows, when they're at shell cottage and Harry reads Voldemort's mind, he sees Hogsmeade which is "still dark, because it was so much further North" (quoting from memory, so probs not exact), but it's Easter, which is after the spring equinox, so it gets light **earlier** further North. In other words, JKR generally doesn't understand that stuff in the sky changes depending on the time of year.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  While everything you say is correct, this isn't as directed at the question as it should be; it reads more like a response to another answer, instead of standing on its own.  ("No, she doesn't explain it but...")

Comment: @DavidW It seems to me to be an answer, it's giving another time where JKR doesn't understand things like this and then ends with essentially the answer. Admittedly it could be a bit more explicit.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I agree with you.  I tried to say that it had good information, but could stand some minor editing to make it clear that it stood on its own, instead of replying to other answers.